# Output groovy list as comma separated string in gsp

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have the following in my controller:

```
render(view: "create", model: [dealInstance: dealInstance, storeName: params.storeName, location: params.location, openEmailClient: true, emailTo: users*.email])
```

And the following in my create.gsp:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  <g:if test="${openEmailClient}">              
    <g:set var="subject" value="${g.message(code: 'deal.created.email.subject')}" scope="page" />
    <g:set var="body" value="${g.message(code: 'deal.created.email.body')}" scope="page" />
    window.location.href = "mailto:${emailTo}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}";
  </g:if>
});
```

This opens the default email client and populate the "To" field.

How can I convert the list of emails to a comma separated string? (Is this even correct? Will most email client accept a comma as the email separator?)

i.e. a@a.com,b@b.com...

Comment: according to email spec (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), commas are the way to go.  Some MS products in the past have had issues with this, btw, (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820868), but I think commas are the best you're going to be able to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the Groovy [`join`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#join%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
"mailto:${emailTo.join(',')}?....
```

Comment: So simple when you see it! Thanks Ian :)